# New azure active directory with powershell

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I would like create a new Active Directory in Azure with powershell.

Do you know the cmdlet to do this ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot **create** Windows Azure Active Directory **tenant** using PowerShell.

First of all, you do not create Azure Active Directory. It is already created and managed by Microsoft. What you create is a **tenant** within Azure Active Directory. And you cannot just create it. Especially using just some API.

Windows Azure AD tenant is being created when someone creates an Office365 Subscription, or Microsoft Intune Subscription, or Windows Azure Subscription and so on.

Read carefully through the entire [article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj573650.aspx), in order to understand what is Windows Azure AD Tenant, how it is created and where it is used.

Comment: Can i create user of tenant via api or powershell ?

Comment: You can create USER via API - https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/users-operations#CreateUser and per PowerShell: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn194096.aspx